# python logging: logger setLevel() is not enforced?

Tags: python, logging

```
fmtter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(msecs)05.1f (%(funcName)s) %(message)s', '%H:%M:%S')

rock_log = '%s/rock.log' % Build.path
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(rock_log, mode='w')
hdlr.setFormatter(fmtter)
hdlr.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

rock_logger = logging.getLogger('rock')
rock_logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```

I have the above logger

`rock_logger.info("hi")` doesnt print anything to the log BUT
`rock_logger.error("hi")` DOES print to the log

I think it has something to do with level but i specifically set it to `logging.DEBUG`

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `rock_logger` is the logger and `hdlr` is the handler. When you try to log something, the logger first checks if it should handle the message (depending on it's own log level). Then it passes the message to the handler. The handler then checks the level against it's own log level and decided whether to write it to the file or not.

Your `rock_logger` might have the logging level set to errors. So it's not passing the messages to the handler when you try `info()` or `debug()`.

```
rock_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: didnt know that handler level do not override the logger's